# Visual Studio Code layout render bug - mouse actions work only in full screen mode

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-10

Has anyone else encountered this annoying situation? In short, there is this **black bar** that appears right above the menu bar and on the left of the sidebar. It causes any mouse actions to fail (unless you position the cursor slightly above the targeted item) and the status bar to be completely hidden...

I tried to reinstall the editor, by making sure all relevant folders in `<user>\AppData\Local\` are removed before I do a fresh download, but it doesn't seem to work.

Important notes:

1) I got this bug after I upgraded Windows 10 evaluation to build 10122;

2) When I hit F11 I am able to use mouse actions well and status bar is visible.

Please help.

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot?

Comment: @BenjaminPasero here it is. http://i.imgur.com/XTxA5i4.png

Comment: Hi @BenjaminPasero. The bug has something to do with my graphics card/driver. I use a NVIDIA GeForce 7100/nForce 630i version 5.73.32.8.1. When I disable the driver obviously I get an ugly looking, fattened display interface, but the visual studio code window renders better (i.e. the dark bar disappears). Do you have insight on how I can get that fixed? Obviously I can't disable the graphics driver forever. Thanks.

Comment: I wonder how Atom editor looks in your setup, if there are graphic issues with VS Code I would assume the same issues with Atom. Can you try?

Comment: I thought about the same thing... But then I just thought of uninstalling the NVIDIA driver and re-installing it again (making sure to tick the "perform a clean install" checkbox and keeping vscode open). It solved it for me, but as soon as I tried to close vscode and open it again the problem remained unresolved.

Comment: Same problem with **Atom**. [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/5vpQDtg.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the update after the upcoming one we plan to update to a more recent version of Chrome (43). We investigate if the issue is fixed by this update.

**Update**

Version 0.5.0 is out and it comes with Chrome 43. Can you try again please?

Comment: If this is a known issue maybe you could shed some light on its origins.

Comment: Just updated to version **0.3.0**. Issue still NOT fixed. Waiting for the next update with rendered upgraded to 43. Current one is **41.0.2272.76**

Comment: The issue got resolved when I upgraded my OS to the latest stable build of the insiders program... Sorry I forgot to let y'all know. But still I don't know what was wrong in the first place.

Comment: For anyone coming back to this 5 years later, definitely a graphics driver bug and still happening...